# Using Rest Service passing json c#

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I'm calling a REST service that returns json

this is what I have so far

```
HttpClient client = CreateClient(this.url, this.username, this.password);
string data_json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Detail, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
//Detail is a class with the json data
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Now, how do I use `data_json`? I need to pass the json to get the response.

Comment: pass that in post body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include it in your post request:

```
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(data_json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent).Result;
```